# Chart comparing two Core Data entities sometimes crashes with "swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Tags: swiftui

Im trying to compare two coredata entities using charts here. I go into a detail view for one club, which shows a chart of that clubs shots. When I select another club from a picker, it should show that clubs shots on the chart in a different color. Sometimes it works, but other times (seemingly at random) it crashes the app and I get an error that says `swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

```
struct ClubCompareChartView: View {
    var club: Club
    var compareClub: Club?
    var body: some View {
        Chart(0..<(club.strokesList.count), id: \.self) { nr in
            PointMark(
                x: .value("X value", nr),
                y: .value("Y value", club.strokesList[nr])
            )
            
            if compareClub != nil{
                PointMark(
                    x: .value("X value", nr),
                    y: .value("Y value", compareClub!.strokesList[nr])
                ).foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Ranges are unsafe with SwiftUI, you should watch “Demystify SwiftUI”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to avoid the index crash.

You could try using `indices` instead of a range **and**
test for out of bound index as shown in the example code.

```
struct ClubCompareChartView: View {
    var club: Club
    var compareClub: Club?
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(club.strokesList.indices, id: \.self) { nr in  // <-- here
            PointMark(
                x: .value("X value", nr),
                y: .value("Y value", club.strokesList[nr])
            )

            if let cmpr = compareClub, nr < cmpr.strokesList.count {  // <--- here
                PointMark(
                    x: .value("X value", nr),
                    y: .value("Y value", cmpr.strokesList[nr])
                ).foregroundStyle(.red)
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach to avoid the index out of range crashes, is using `enumerated()` like this:

```
struct ClubCompareChartView: View {
    var club: Club
    var compareClub: Club?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Chart {
            ForEach(Array(club.strokesList.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { nr, element in
                PointMark(
                    x: .value("X value", nr),
                    y: .value("Y value", element)
                ).foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
            
            if let cmpr = compareClub {
                ForEach(Array(cmpr.strokesList.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { nr, element in
                    PointMark(
                        x: .value("X value", nr),
                        y: .value("Y value", element)
                    ).foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but `indices` are unsafe, Demystify SwiftUI around 33:40. It is better than ranges but still unsafe. They describe this exact scenario.

Comment: no problema, if you don't like `indices` use the alternative `enumerated` approach. Note, I think `indices` is valid in this particular example, if the array elements are some primitive types, eg Double or Int